# Uniform convergence fails if there is a sequence with

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Show that a sequence of functions $\langle f_n \rangle$ fails to converge uniformly to a function $f$ on a set $E$ if and only if there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that a sequence $\langle x_k \rangle$ of points from $E$ and a subsequence $\langle f_{n_k}\rangle$ can be found such that $|f_{n_k}(x_k) - f(x_k)| \geq \varepsilon$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Trivial?

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\langle f_n \rangle$ fails to converge uniformly to a function $f$ on $E$. By definition, this means

$$\exists \, \varepsilon >0 , \forall \, N \in \mathbb{N}, |f_n(x) -f(x)| \geq \varepsilon$$

for some $x \in E$ and some $n \geq N$. Choose $\langle f_{n_k} \rangle = \langle f_n \rangle$ and choose $\langle x_k \rangle$ to be any sequence in $E$. Then we are done.

Comment: $\langle x_k \rangle$ can't just be anything in the scenario of the negative result; there is an existential quantifier over $x$ in the inline statement which you have dropped.

Comment: @Ian $``$for some $x \in E"  \implies \exists \, x \in E$

Comment: Right, but you're not taking into account that the $x$ you pick is not just arbitrary in your second to last sentence.

Comment: To see the point, think about $f_n : [0,1] \to [0,1],f_n(x)=x^n$. Here the $\langle x_k \rangle$ you are going to get will have to converge to $1$ from the left or at least have a subsequence that does so.

Comment: @Ian for $f_n(x)=x^n$, if we let $x= 1-\frac{1}{n}$, we note that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |f_n(x)-0| = |f_n(x)| = (1-\frac{1}{n})^n = \frac{1}{e}$

Comment: Yes, the result is true for that example. I'm saying your proof in your question doesn't achieve the goal, because you don't use the given property to select $x_k$ or $n_k$.